# Trying to understand upsert - data loader

Tags: data-loader, upsert

Im trying to understand how to use upsert.. for example there`s :

ID = 1600.

Type = Shipping To.

and

ID = 1600.
Type = Billing to.

Can I use upsert to update record where ID = 1600 and type = shipping.. and insert new record with ID = 1600 and type = Billing to, if record with "billing to" doesnt exist?

Comment: Refer this article for more information about upsert operation:- https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/all-about-upsert-and-external-id-in-dataloader-and-apex-videos/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the same recordId = 1600, if you perform `upsert` then it will only update the existing record and not new record will be created.

Your use case can be solved in the following way.

1. Create an `External Id` field and populate the external id field value with a combination of `Id + type`.
2. Now based on this `External Id` field you can perform `upsert` operation. In that scenario, existing record `Id = 1600` with `type = Shipping To` will get updated and new record `Id = 1600` with `type = Billing to` gets inserted.
3. Since, `External Id` is new field, so you need to perform a data migration to populate this field value for historical records.

Answer (score 1):

If both records have the same ID only the last operation's changes will be reflected once the upsert is complete. If you want a new record inserted you need to include the data for that record **with a new, unique record ID** in your upsert file.

[Here is somewhere to start for understanding record IDs.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004383&language=en_US&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1)

[How does "upsert" work?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MUaSQAW)